# Docker Cannot Connect Localhost But Can Connect via Vscode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile

I'm new with Docker and learning Docker images while creating a custom node.js image for my dev env. (Windows 10 WSL2 Docker latest)

`TL;DR`
I created a custom image as below and created a container from this custom image. When I try a `gatsby start` command (or an express server start), it's supposed to connect to `http://localhost:8000/` (tried `127.0.0.1`, ip address, `host.docker.internal`) however it doesn't. When I attach the container to VSCode, somehow VSCode creates a new auto-forwarded port which I can connect with. I attached the details below.

So, does anyone know why I can't connect to port `8000` on my localhost? What am I missing?

The custom image

```
FROM debian:latest
ENV HOME /root

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Upgrade
RUN apt update && apt -y upgrade

RUN apt install -y apt-utils software-properties-common python3 git curl

RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh \
&& echo "Host *" >> /root/.ssh/config \
&& echo "    StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /root/.ssh/config \
&& echo "    GlobalKnownHostsFile  /dev/null" >> /root/.ssh/config \
&& echo "    UserKnownHostsFile    /dev/null" >> /root/.ssh/config

# Upgrade
RUN apt update && apt -y upgrade

RUN apt install -y python3-pip

# Set py alias
RUN echo 'alias python=python3 && alias py=python3' >> ~/.bashrc

# Install nvm to install npm and node.js
ENV NVM_DIR /home/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 16.3.0
RUN mkdir /home/.nvm && \
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash && \
    chmod +x /home/.nvm/nvm.sh && \
    . /home/.nvm/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install --latest-npm "$NODE_VERSION" && \
    nvm alias default "$NODE_VERSION" && \
    nvm use default && \
    DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION=$(nvm version default) && \
    ln -sf /home/.nvm/versions/node/$DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs && \
    ln -sf /home/.nvm/versions/node/$DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION/bin/node /usr/bin/node && \
    ln -sf /home/.nvm/versions/node/$DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm

RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli

WORKDIR /app

VOLUME ["/app"]

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 3001
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 8001
EXPOSE 8002
EXPOSE 8003
EXPOSE 8004
EXPOSE 8005
EXPOSE 8006
EXPOSE 8007
EXPOSE 8008
EXPOSE 8009
EXPOSE 8010
```

Then I started the container with command

```
docker run --name mycontainer -v ${pwd}:/app --publish 8000:8000 -it nodejs-dev-img /bin/bash
```

The image successfully runs and I can connect.

`http://localhost:8000/` doesn't connect.

When I attach VSCode to the container and run, VSCode creates a auto forwarded port, which I can use to connect as below:

[image: a auto forwarded port]

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you,

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff in the Dockerfile – I'd probably omit all of it and just start `FROM node:16.3.0` – but I don't see where you `COPY` the application code in or set the `CMD` to run?  The `docker run` command you show wouldn't start the application either, it just runs a shell?

Comment: That's right. The docker container has a volume for the app and i start the application manually for now.

Answer (score 0):

All right, it seems the answer is using the `0.0.0.0` host instead of `127.0.0.1`. So with gatsby, the command is

```
gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0
```